# python 2.7 - how to turn a string into a list when seperators are digits and '\\n'

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, split, newline

for example i have the string :

```
"hello0there\\nhow3are6you1today?"
```

what i want to get is :

```
["hello", "there", "how", "are", "you", "today?"]
```

the digits represent spaces, and the `\\n` is a new line.
i've tried `split()` to do it but it can only get 2 arguements and not more, so it's not optinal.

i also found this :

```
filter(None, re.split("['1234567890']+", string_to_split))
```

which works fine for the digits, yet not for the `'\\n'`.
is there any way to split the string by the digits and the `'\\n'` in one action?

i cant figure out a way to split it in two separated functions because once I've created a list i cannot split it again.

if anyone knows of a way to do so, please help me. thanks

Comment: Just add whitespace (`\s`) to your regex (and note that digits are just `\d`).

Comment: Is this a raw or a normal string? That would result in `\\n` or `\n`. Both are one or two `\ ` and an `n`, not a newline.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I't wont work again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `\s` and `\\n` to your regex :

```
>>> s="hello0there\\nhow3are6you1today?"
>>> re.split(r'[\d\s\\n]*',s)
['hello', 'there', 'how', 'are', 'you', 'today?']
```

For getting ride of splitting with `n`'s in your strings you can use a positive look behind and and an logical or :

```
>>> re.split(r'[\d\s\\]|(?<=\\)n',s)
```

But since it might produce an empty string you can use a list comprehension to get ride of that.

```
>>> [i for i in re.split(r'[\d\s\\]|(?<=\\)n',s) if i]
```

Comment: You need more backslashes (or `r''`)!

Comment: is there a way to split by '\n' only together ( not by a single 'n'? beacause i ran that on a list with words containing the letter n and it splited words too.. @jonrsharpe

Comment: @Maya then make them alternatives, using `|`, rather than a class of characters.

Comment: can you shoe me ? an example.. @jonrsharpe